# How to mock a request in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, mocking

How to mock a request in ruby on rails

I am making a call to multiple external sites via API and facing lot of failures in the response due to net read timeout error and parameters errror , run time errors, etc.

I want to mock the request before making a original call to the API. So that i can avoid more failures in my app.

Can any one help me ?

Comment: look at this gem https://github.com/vcr/vcr

Comment: For unit-test, you should always mock responses. For integration tests, sometimes you need to go through full lifecycle and still be able to mock 3rd parties. Ref https://beeceptor.com, it can help you create an interceptor to wrap third party APIs and help you mock. _(disclaimer: i'm the author)_

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using the [VCR gem](https://github.com/vcr/vcr), it records HTTP request for you, the first time you run your tests. For subsequent tests VCR uses the previously recorded HTTP response.

This should solve your timeout errors and allow you to work with external API's more easily.

Checkout these resources for more info:

- https://www.relishapp.com/vcr/vcr/docs
- http://natashatherobot.com/vcr-gem-rails-rspec/